# WPF - src type not found

Tags: c#, wpf, src

I tried to use this link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff407130.aspx . But whenever I debug it for some reason it throws an error :

> The type 'src:MyVirtualizingStackPanel' was not found. Verify that you
>   are not missing an assembly reference and that all referenced
>   assemblies have been built.

And another error:

> 'src' is an undeclared prefix. Line 13, position 22.' XML is not valid

I copied the class and methods into the MainWindow class and the XAML.
Am I missing anything here?

Comment: It sounds like you need to ad an XML Namespace to point the class that you defined. Take a look at the [XAML Namespaces and Namespace Mapping for WPF XAML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms747086.aspx) page on MSDN to find out more.

Comment: The name-space is set automatically as I start a project so it shouldn't be the problem in my opinion..

Comment: Can you please explain exactly what that means?

Comment: I already have the namespace name which is Movie_Editor, my project name.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At the end of the day, *you* are mistaken about your XML Namespace. If you type your error minus the name into a search engine, you will see something:

> The type was not found. Verify that you are not missing an assembly reference and that all referenced assemblies have been built

*All* of the results will point to the fact that you have *not* provided the correct XML Namespace for your project. Now we don't have your project in front of us... only you do, so only you can work out what your Namespace problem is. You mentioned something in a comment that made me suspicious.

You said *The name-space is set automatically*, but when I asked you to tell me exactly what that meant, you didn't, so I still don't know what you meant. Either way, it doesn't matter, but that *could* be a cause of your problem. Here are some other *possible* causes:

> Maybe your `MyVirtualizingStackPanel` class is defined in a different class/project to where you specified.
>
> Maybe you need to include the `assembly=XXX` part of the XML Namespace.
>
> Maybe you have not included the CLR Namespace in your `MyVirtualizingStackPanel` class.

Either way, this is definitely an XML Namespace problem, so just keep looking/experimenting and you'll find the problem eventually. You can find out exactly how to add an XML Namespace from the [XAML Namespaces and Namespace Mapping for WPF XAML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms747086.aspx) page on MSDN.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I suppose I have no knowledge in that matter. How am I creating a name-space for MyVirtualizingStackPanel class?

Comment: You're asking me??? I don't know how you created your Namespace. Either way, I provided you with a link in my first comment (and now added to my answer) to a page that fully explains how to do it correctly.

Comment: I have managed to find a solution with your help, thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you need to specify the namespace where the `MyVirtualizingStackPanel` class comes from.

In the beginning of your XAML, add:

```
xmlns:src="clr-namespace:XXX"
```

where `XXX` is the namespace.

See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms747086%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#Mapping_To_Custom_Classes_and_Assemblies).

Comment: I did try that, Let's say the namespace is Movie_Editor so : <Window x:Class="Movie_Editor.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:src="clr-namespace:Movie_Editor"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="1020" Width="1280" ResizeMode="NoResize"> , It still shows the same error.

Answer (score 0):

You have to import in the xaml the namespace `src`to use this
On the top of the page you do:

```
xmlns:src="yourProjectPath"
```

than you can use the `MyVirtualizingStackPane` class.

Answer (score 0):

add the XMLNS in the top,

Here look at the example

```
xmlns:toolkit="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Toolkit"
```

Answer (score -1):

Add a reference to 'PresentationFramework' - you will find it in:
Add reference... -> Assemblies -> Framework